# when I click on checkbox price, products will be shown of those price

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set price range slider with input fields to show products with price with `jQuery` and `javascript`; Now I want to show those products when someone click on `checkbox` which have between price.

**HTML and JS:**

```js
      var details = {"books": 20,"pens": 60,"ink": 90,"table": 120,
      "chair": 170,"shoes": 220,"boots": 320,
      };

      $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".price_range").slider({
          max: 500,
          range: true,
          values: [0, 500],
          change: function(event, ui) {
              getDetails(ui.values[0], ui.values[1]);
          }
      });
       var current = $(".price_range").slider("option", "values");
      getDetails(current[0], current[1]);  });

    function getDetails(minimum, maximum) {
      $("#range").val("" + minimum);
      $("#range-1").val("" + maximum);
      var result = "<table><tr><th>Product Name</th>  <th>Price (in $)</th></tr>";
      for (var item in details) {
          if (details[item] >= minimum && details[item] <= maximum) {
              result += "<tr><td>" + item + "</td><td>" + details[item] + "</td></tr>";
          }
      }
      result += "</table>";
      $(".output").html(result);}
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".input_slides").change(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $(".price_range").slider("values",  
     $this.attr('index'), $this.val());});});
```

```html
   
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="price_range"></div>       
      <div class="slider_input">
      <form>
        <input type="text" index="0" id="range" class="input_slides">
        <input type="text" index="1" id="range-1" class="input_slides">
        <br><br>
        <h4>Filter price by between price</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
        <label> 0-100 </label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
        <label> 100-200</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
        <label> 200-300</label><br>
     </form>
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**JSFiddle:**

[jsfiddle link of the whole code example](https://jsfiddle.net/akhlaque/n48L1oft/3/)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` loop to iterate through all checkboxes which are *checked* and using `value` of checkboxes which are checked append rows inside your tables.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var details = {
  "books": 20,
  "pens": 60,
  "ink": 90,
  "table": 120,
  "chair": 170,
  "shoes": 220,
  "boots": 320,
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".input_slides").change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".price_range").slider("values", $this.attr('index'), $this.val());
  });

  $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var result = "<table><tr><th>Product Name</th>  <th>Price (in $)</th></tr>";
    if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0) {
      //loop through checkboxs checked
      $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val().split("-") //split values and pass inside ifs
        for (var item in details) {
          if (details[item] >= value[0] && details[item] <= value[1]) {
            result += "<tr><td>" + item + "</td><td>" + details[item] + "</td></tr>";
          }
        }
      })

      result += "</table>";
      $(".output").html(result);

    } else {
      //call your fn to show all
      //getDetails(0, 500);

    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="price_range"></div>
      <div class="slider_input">
        <form>
          <h4>Filter price by between price</h4>
          <!--added values-->
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="0-100">
          <label> 0-100 </label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="100-200">
          <label> 100-200</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="200-300">
          <label> 200-300</label><br>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
```